# Dynamically consume a different data object depending on the option selected

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, codesandbox

I have a data object containing 2 arrays ( list of teams name )

```
const data = {
  Liga: ['Alaves','Atletico', 'Barcelona', 'Betis'],
  Premier: ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Everton", 'Liverpool']
};
```

Based on the value i select ( Liga or Premier ) i get the list of my teams.

These teams have two different data score results `scoresliga` and `scorespremier`

```
const scoresliga = [
  { day: '0', Alaves: -6, Atletico: -1, Barcelona: -2, Betis: -6},
  { day: '1', Alaves: -7, Atletico: 1, Barcelona: -2, Betis: -6}
];

const scorespremier = [
  { day: '0', Arsenal: -6, Chelsea: -1, Everton: -2, Liverpool: -6},
  { day: '1', Arsenal: -7, Chelsea: 1, Everton: -2, Betis: -6}
];
```

My problem is i have to find a way that when i select 'Liga' i have to consume the `scoresliga` object and if i select 'Premier' i have to consume `scorespremier`

This would be also resolving the problem that i have when i calculate the average of the teams that at the moment it is **not** a general function.

This the snippet of the function using `scoresliga` data object, but it needs to be a share function for both Ligas ( Premier and Liga ).

```
const getAverage = team => {

  if (isNaN(scoresliga[0][team])) return null;

  return scoresliga.map(x => x[team]).reduce((a, c) => a + c) / scoresliga.length;
};
```

**I have reproduced my case, *have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-s5jj2?fontsize=14)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add additional property to getAverage

```
const getAverage = (league, team) => {

  if (isNaN(league[0][team])) return null;

  return league.map(x => x[team]).reduce((a, c) => a + c) / 
     league.length;
};
```

[image: Edit Recharts Examples]

Also create some mapping in scores

```
const scores = {
  Liga: [
    { day: "0", Alaves: -6, Atletico: -1, Barcelona: -2, Betis: -6 },
    { day: "1", Alaves: -7, Atletico: 1, Barcelona: -2, Betis: -6 }
  ],
  Premier: [
    { day: "0", Arsenal: -6, Chelsea: -1, Everton: -2, Liverpool: -6 },
    { day: "1", Arsenal: -7, Chelsea: 1, Everton: -2, Betis: -6 }
  ]
};
```

And in the Chart.js

```
<span>{getAverage(scores[this.state.selectedLeague], this.state.selectedTeam)}</span>
```

Also, update

```
handleLeagueChange = event => {
    const selectedLeague = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ selectedLeague: selectedLeague }, () => {
      this.setState({ selectedTeam: data[selectedLeague][0] });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Do you mind to edit my codesandbox to accept the answer?

Comment: The average is not calculated here https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-s5jj2

Comment: @Koala7 i have added link to CodeSandbox, which calculates averages.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add a key `championShip` into arrays:

```
const scoresliga = [
  { day: '0', championShip: 'Liga', Alaves: -6, Atletico: -1, Barcelona: -2, Betis: -6},
  { day: '1', championShip: 'Liga', Alaves: -7, Atletico: 1, Barcelona: -2, Betis: -6, championShip: 'Liga'}
];

const scorespremier = [
  { day: '0', championShip: 'Premier',  Arsenal: -6, Chelsea: -1, Everton: -2, Liverpool: -6},
  { day: '1', championShip: 'Premier', Arsenal: -7, Chelsea: 1, Everton: -2, Betis: -6},
  { day: '1', championShip: 'Premier', Chelsea: 1, Everton: -2, Betis: -6}
];
```

Then it would be easier to manipulate by your arrays and you can have one array:

```
let merged = scoresliga.concat(scorespremier);

let desiredTeam = 'Arsenal';
const filteredByTeam = merged.filter(f=> f.championShip === 'Premier' && f[desiredTeam]);
const averageByTeamQuantity = filteredByTeam.reduce((a,c) =>{
  a += +c[desiredTeam];
  return a;
}, 0)/ filteredByTeam.length;


console.log(averageByTeamQuantity);
```